# How to set azure experiment name from the code after 2021-08-18 SDK change?

Tags: azuremlsdk

[On 2021-08-18 Microsoft (for our convenience ?) made the following changes to their Azure ML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/azure-machine-learning-release-notes):

**Azure Machine Learning Experimentation User Interface.** **Run Display Name.**

- The Run Display Name is a new, editable and optional display name that can be assigned to a run.
- This name can help with more effectively tracking, organizing and discovering the runs.
- The Run Display Name is defaulted to an adjective_noun_guid format (Example: awesome_watch_2i3uns).
- This default name can be edited to a more customizable name. This can be edited from the Run details page in the Azure Machine Learning studio user interface.

Before this change to the SDK, Run Display Name = experiment name + hash.
I was assigning the experiment name from the SDK:

```
from azureml.core import Experiment
experiment_name = 'yus_runExperiment'
experiment=Experiment(ws,experiment_name)
run = experiment.submit(src)
```

After the change the Run Display Names are auto-generated.

[image]

I do not want to manually edit/change the Run Display Name as I may sometimes run 100-s experiments a day.

I tried to find an answer in the Microsoft documentation, but my attempts have failed.

**Is there an Azure SDK function to assign the Run Display Name ?**

Comment: Your headline suggests you want to know how to change the experiment name, but your last line asks for how to change the `run display name`. You might want to so that the question in the body text and headline matches.

Answer (score 3):

Just tested in sdk v1.38.0.

You could do like this:

```
from azureml.core import Experiment
experiment_name = 'yus_runExperiment'
experiment=Experiment(ws,experiment_name)
run = experiment.submit(src)
run.display_name = "Training"
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLFvd.png)

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It works. I do find it odd that you have to update the name after the run is started, instead of adding a display name to the config, before submitting, but that is hardly the fault of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's undocumented (so try at your own risk I guess) but I successfully changed the display name using the following python code.

```
from azureml.core import Experiment, Run, Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name=<name>)
run = Run(exp, <run id>)
run.display_name = <new display name>
```

Comment: changing run.display_name does not change Display name that in shown in 
Home>Experiments>experiment_name

Comment: The Run display name and the experiment name are two different things. The experiment name is set in this line Experiment(workspace=ws, name=<name>.

Answer (score 1):

Tested inside notebook on AML compute instance and with `azureml-sdk` version `1.37.0`:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Run
run = Run.get_context()
if "OfflineRun" not in run.id:
    # works for an offline run on azureml compute instance
    workspace = run.experiment.workspace
else:
    # For an AML run, do your auth for AML here like:
    # workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name, auth)
    pass # remove that pass for sure when you're running inside AML cluster
run.display_name = "CustomDisplayName"
run.description = "CustomDescription"
print(f"workspace has the run {run.display_name} with the description {run.description}")
```

Output:

`workspace has the run CustomDisplayName with the description CustomDescription`