# change run display name azureml

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

same problem as this however using script run config  [How to set azure experiment name from the code after 2021-08-18 SDK change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857591/how-to-set-azure-experiment-name-from-the-code-after-2021-08-18-sdk-change). Tried all the solutions however did not work

```
src = ScriptRunConfig(
            source_directory=".",
            script='train.py',
            arguments=training_params,
            compute_target=compute_name,
            environment = conda_env
            )
        #DataReference for underlying RunConfiguration object
        src.run_config.data_references = {Data_Refrence.data_reference_name: Data_Refrence.to_config()}

try:
    run = exp.submit(config=src)
    run.display_name = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The link which was mentioned in the question regarding the SO thread is the same procedure we can follow programmatical manner. There is an alternative procedure to change the name through **Machine Learning Studio** portal.

1. Open Machine Learning Studio
2. Create a pipeline for prediction based on your requirements.
3. Open the **project** which you created. It will show the **Jobs** in the left panel like mentioned in image

[image]

4. After clicking on it, select the job which you want to modify the name

[image],

Click on the edit button over there beside the name

5. It will open an edit name panel and give the name which needs to be displayed and click on Save

[image]

Comment: don't want to do this manually as there are 1000s of jobs want it done in code

Comment: Can you please tell the pattern of the job names you are planning to give.

Comment: call jobs  ML_Project

Comment: Can you please give the code block which you tried if there is any update on that. So, that it will be helpful to reproduce the issue.